# Ruby on Rails5/ cancancan/ devise - Implementing access restrictions for different kind of users (i.e. making user A see different pages than user B)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rails-admin, cancancan

I’m trying to set up certain access restrictions for my website, meaning that I want the admin to see different pages than the normal user. I’ve used devise for the user authentication and cancancan for the access restriction. Unfortunately, I am not quite sure how to implement it with cancancan.

I marked the users by assigning them 2 different roles (booleans) - admin and charity. Basically, I want the admin to land on page A when logging in and he should also have access to page B and C (and the rails_admin). The charity user is supposed to land on page D and should have access to page E and F.

I tried adding the following code to app/model/ability.rb but unfortunately without any luck:

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)
if user.admin_role?
  can :manage, :page A
  can :manage, :page B
  can :manage, :page C
  can :access, :rails_admin       # only allow admin users to access Rails Admin
end
if user.charity_role?
  can :manage, page D
  can :manage, page E
  can :manage, page F
end
```

Does anyone know what I’m supposed to change? And also how do I ensure that the admin lands on page A and the charity lands on page D after logging in?

I’d be grateful for any help!

Comment: Where you have `page X` should normally be a object Class that you are giving access to (ability), so I'm a bit confused about what you are expecting. Maybe see here [link](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/defining-abilities). The pages that are presented to the user are then controlled by the Controllers and Views.

Comment: Oh okay, so is this not the correct place to define which pages the admin has access to and which the user has access to?

Comment: Thanks for the link by the way. It was helpful to read even though it did not fully clarify my question

Answer (score 0):

You can best control the display of the web pages in either the Rails Views or the Rails Controllers. So for example in a View with ERB you could control the display of a link to edit an Article object with:

```
<% if can? :update, @article %>
  <%= link_to "Edit", edit_article_path(@article) %>
<% end %>
```

This would assume that in you `app/models/ability.rb` you have something like:

```
can :update, Article       # user can update Articles
```

Or perhaps if you want to display a completely different View template? Then do this in the controller. A crude (untested) snippet that might be in articles_controller.rb action for 'show':

```
if can? :read, @article 
   template = 'articles/show'
else
   template = 'articles/not_allowed'
end
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { render :template => template }
  format.js { render :template => template }
end
```